# Rails checkbox to get json value of selected records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

Hi I have a form in rails and this is the code

```
 <%= form_tag getjson_products_path do  %>
<% @products.each do |product|  %>
    <%= check_box_tag "product_ids[]",product.id , false%>
   <%= product.name %>
   <%= product.category %>
   <%= product.price %>
   <%= link_to 'Show', product %>
   <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product) %>
   <%= link_to 'Destroy', product, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
  <br>
<% end %>
 <%= submit_tag "submit" %>
<br>
<% end %>
```

and I have written one method in products controller

```
   def getjson
    #stuff to do
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

and this is my routes file

```
 resources :products do
   collection do
    get 'getjson'
 end
end
```

I want is to get json value of selected products , but whenever I click submit it says routes error what I have to do and how to get json value for selected records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller change like this

```
def getjson
    if params[:product_ids]
       @products = Product.find(params[:product_ids])
       render json: @products
     end
  end
```

thats all it will works